# How to upload a file using Laravel with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed a Laravel app on an Elastic Beanstalk environment and all of my file upload functionality is not working. I've looked everywhere online, but nothing can solve this issue.

When I'm uploading a document, everything seems to work. No error is shown. However, the file doesn't actually get uploaded. This makes me think that it's the permissions causing it, however, I have set the upload folders to 755 using .ebextensions config and the issue is still there.

*.ebextensions/{appname}.config*

```
container_commands:
    change_permissions:
        command: chmod 755 /var/www/html/storage/app/public
```

Does anybody know the cause of this issue? I'm trying to avoid using S3 if possible as using Elastic Beanstalk is only temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution to this problem. The reason was because I needed to update the storage link server side to the public storage folder. So the storage link in /public/ had to be deleted, and then recreated server side

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

To store files I suggest using a S3 bucket. Use the amazon SDK to do it. For java, see 
[com.amazonaws.services.s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) 
putObject Interface AmazonS3.

Of course, your file-saving code should be pluggable, with at least two implementations. One implementation saving the file to the local disk and another for storing it in S3. Your startup code should wire the correct implementation.